# thymeleaf - table tr th:each with multiple condition th:if

Tags: spring, html-table, thymeleaf

I want to make a table with some conditions. If the item is lower than 0.33% of stock, the row color must set Red. If the item is greater than 0.33% and lower than 0.66%, the row color must set orange, and if the item is greater than 0.66%, so the row color must set yellow.

I am using th:each in each tag TR, and give th:if, but only shown one row with stock greater than 0.66%

```
<tr th:each="item: ${items}" th:if="${item.sisa/item.stok &lt; 33/100 }" style="background-color:red" >                          
    <td th:text="${item.id}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.name}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.stok}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.sisa}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.harga}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.supplier.name}">A Smoke Test</td>
</tr>
<tr th:each="item: ${items}" th:if="${item.sisa/item.stok &gt; 33/100 and item.sisa/item.stok &lt; 66/100}" style="background-color:orange" >                                
    <td th:text="${item.id}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.name}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.stok}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.sisa}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.harga}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.supplier.name}">A Smoke Test</td>
</tr>
<tr th:each="item: ${items}" th:if="${item.sisa/item.stok &gt; 66/100}" style="background-color:yellow">
    <td th:text="${item.id}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.name}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.stok}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.sisa}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.harga}">A Smoke Test</td>
    <td th:text="${item.supplier.name}">A Smoke Test</td>
</tr>
```

i have data sample with 0.22%, 0.77% and 0.99%, but only data sample with 0.99% show up.

---

**Problem Solved!**

Instead of using thymeleaf th:if, I am using datatable createdRow, more easy to use than using thymeleaf th:if tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this too complicated.

I would write a java (or js) method which returns you the desired color (-class) based on the percent input.

This will make your template a lot more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Yes, i am. I already change it with datatable createdRow. More easy to use. Thanks for the respone.